# Displaying counts for all Dates in to multiple columns - Advance SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this.

```
Dept   |           TicketCode                 |  AsOfDate  |FixedBy | FixedDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
merlin | ACE4E957-62C9-4447-A39E-AAA6928C7DD3 | 2014-03-04 | Mark   | 2014-03-05 
merlin | 95C5AF27-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 | 2014-02-27 | Mark   | 2014-03-06
merlin | 581CE204-3586-E211-A244-002481E28F48 | 2014-02-27 | Ravi   | 2014-03-06
merlin | E9E6C0C6-7562-4265-82B0-5D14E3FEC674 | 2014-03-17 | Olive  | 2014-03-18
omega  | 1922DD26-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 | 2014-03-18 | Sandy  | 2014-03-19
merlin | 94E6EF27-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 | 2014-03-18 | Ravi   | 2014-03-19
omega  | E7F5EF27-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 | 2014-03-18 | Sandy  | 2014-03-19
omega  | CF8D4227-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 | 2014-03-19 | Olive  | 2014-03-20
omega  | 1A904227-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 | 2014-03-19 | Ravi   | 2014-03-20
merlin | DCA94227-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 | 2014-03-19 | Steve  | 2014-03-20
Pine   | 349E868F-DFFB-43DC-B50E-A9FFBF553908 | 2014-03-19 | Steve  | 2014-03-20
merlin | 281FDD26-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 | 2014-03-20 | Olive  | 2014-03-21
omega  | FDB6AF27-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 | 2014-03-20 | Steve  | 2014-03-21
omega  | B8A1A320-FD0E-45AD-8A5D-9E92529806CD | 2014-04-29 | Ravi   | 2014-04-30
omega  | B8A1A320-FD0E-45AD-8A5D-9E92529806CD | 2014-04-29 | Olive  | 2014-04-30
Pine   | 5369D01E-BA2E-4AA6-A228-A9073BC0AE1B | 2014-04-29 | Steve  | 2014-04-30
Pine   | 1B59E55F-4AFB-490C-901C-82E0743748C6 | 2014-04-30 | Sandy  | 2014-05-01
Pine   | B326348F-E838-42FD-BECB-A8071175BC27 | 2014-04-30 | Ravi   | 2014-05-01
Merlin | B326348F-E838-42FD-BECB-A8071175BC27 | 2014-04-30 | Sandy  | 2014-05-01
```

now my requirement is in such a way that the table which i am supposed to display should be having
variable columns based on the given date range, and also i am supposed to count the "TicketCode"
with filter of dept, FixedBy, FixedDate.

To Put it Simple, This is what i am supposed to get.

--Given dates range

```
@start_date = '2014-03-05'
@end_date = '2014-03-08'

Dept   | FixedBy | 2014-03-05 | 2014-03-06 | 2014-03-07  | 2014-03-08 | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
merlin |   Mark  |     20     |     111    |     24      |     853    |
merlin |   Ravi  |     26     |     456    |     289     |     463    |
merlin |   Mark  |     85     |     81     |     24      |     801    |
merlin |   Steve |     75     |     0      |     0       |     1157   |
merlin |   Sandy |     0      |     78     |     24      |     789    |
merlin |   Mark  |     166    |     110    |     0       |     176    |
omega  |   Ravi  |     126    |     7456   |     289     |     63     |
omega  |   Mark  |     885    |     81     |     284     |     01     |
omega  |   Steve |     975    |     0      |     0       |     157    |
omega  |   Sandy |     90     |     78     |     24      |     79     |
omega  |   Mark  |     166    |     10     |     0       |     76     |
Pine   |   Sandy |     0      |     78     |     24      |     789    |
Pine   |   Mark  |     166    |     10     |     0       |     106    |
Pine   |   Ravi  |     126    |     746    |     289     |     63     |
```

> NOTE: Count is base on Ticket Code, Date range is not fixed. Code can contain `#temp tables`

Mark might work for all the depts, but we only want the dept statics for the given dates and contributed progress.

**I have tried every available resources i can find**.
I just couldn't pass through.

**FYI:** Date range is given manually, so column's count differs.
Code can contain `#temp tables` but no creation functions (i am not Admin).

Many many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code for MS-SQL that will give the results you are looking for.  It creates a dynamics sSQL script and executes this to get the results.   If this does not solve your problem 100% I hope it at least points you in the correct direction.

```
CREATE TABLE  #Data (Dept VARCHAR(20),TicketCode VARCHAR(100), AsOfDate DATETIME, FixedBy VARCHAR(10), FixedDate DATETIME)

DECLARE @StartDate      AS  DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate        AS  DATETIME
DECLARE @ProcessDate    AS  DATETIME
DECLARE @sSQL           AS  VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dtString       AS  VARCHAR(100)

SET @StartDate  = '2014-03-19'
SET @EndDate    = '2014-03-21'

INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('merlin ',' ACE4E957-62C9-4447-A39E-AAA6928C7DD3 ',' 2014-03-04 ',' Mark   ',' 2014-03-05 ')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('merlin ',' 95C5AF27-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-02-27 ',' Mark   ',' 2014-03-06')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('merlin ',' 581CE204-3586-E211-A244-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-02-27 ',' Ravi   ',' 2014-03-06')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('merlin ',' E9E6C0C6-7562-4265-82B0-5D14E3FEC674 ',' 2014-03-17 ',' Olive  ',' 2014-03-18')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('omega  ',' 1922DD26-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-03-18 ',' Sandy  ',' 2014-03-19')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('merlin ',' 94E6EF27-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-03-18 ',' Ravi   ',' 2014-03-19')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('omega  ',' E7F5EF27-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-03-18 ',' Sandy  ',' 2014-03-19')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('omega  ',' CF8D4227-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-03-19 ',' Olive  ',' 2014-03-20')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('omega  ',' 1A904227-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-03-19 ',' Sandy   ',' 2014-03-19')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('merlin ',' DCA94227-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-03-19 ',' Steve  ',' 2014-03-20')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('Pine   ',' 349E868F-DFFB-43DC-B50E-A9FFBF553908 ',' 2014-03-19 ',' Steve  ',' 2014-03-20')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('merlin ',' 281FDD26-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-03-20 ',' Olive  ',' 2014-03-21')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('omega  ',' FDB6AF27-3211-E211-8E73-002481E28F48 ',' 2014-03-20 ',' Steve  ',' 2014-03-21')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('omega  ',' B8A1A320-FD0E-45AD-8A5D-9E92529806CD ',' 2014-04-29 ',' Ravi   ',' 2014-04-30')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('omega  ',' B8A1A320-FD0E-45AD-8A5D-9E92529806CD ',' 2014-04-29 ',' Olive  ',' 2014-04-30')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('Pine   ',' 5369D01E-BA2E-4AA6-A228-A9073BC0AE1B ',' 2014-04-29 ',' Steve  ',' 2014-04-30')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('Pine   ',' 1B59E55F-4AFB-490C-901C-82E0743748C6 ',' 2014-04-30 ',' Sandy  ',' 2014-05-01')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('Pine   ',' B326348F-E838-42FD-BECB-A8071175BC27 ',' 2014-04-30 ',' Ravi   ',' 2014-05-01')
INSERT INTO #Data (Dept, TicketCode, AsOfDate, FixedBy, FixedDate) VALUES('Merlin ',' B326348F-E838-42FD-BECB-A8071175BC27 ',' 2014-04-30 ',' Sandy  ',' 2014-05-01')

SET @ProcessDate = @StartDate 

SET @sSQL = 'SELECT Dept,FixedBy '

/*Create the Dynamics SQL for the Columns*/
WHILE @ProcessDate < @EndDate
    BEGIN
        SET @dtString = CAST(YEAR(@ProcessDate) AS CHAR(4)) + '_'  +  CAST(MONTH(@ProcessDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '_' + CAST(DAY(@ProcessDate) AS VARCHAR(2))
        SET @sSQL = @sSQL + ',
            SUM(CASE WHEN FixedDate = ''' + CAST(@ProcessDate AS CHAR(20)) +  ''' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS dt_' + @dtString
        SET @ProcessDate = @ProcessDate + 1
    END 
SET
    @sSQL = @sSQL +  ' FROM #Data GROUP BY Dept,FixedBy ORDER BY Dept,FixedBy '

SELECT  @sSQL /*To see what will execute*/ 

EXECUTE (@sSQL)  /*Run the Query to return results*/ 

DROP TABLE #Data  /*Remove table*/
```

Comment: It works Just like a Charm. This does solve my problem 100%. Thank you so much. I know i have to use a loop but couldn't think of where to start. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively easy to solve with dynamic pivot. However, your results don't match your data -- there are only two rows in sample data for range between '2014-03-05' and '2014-03-08'.

Here's the code:

```
declare @start_date as date,
@end_date as date;

select @start_date = '2014-03-05', @end_date = '2014-03-08';

declare @collist nvarchar(max)
set @collist = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(convert(varchar(8), FixedDate, 112)) 
    from #t -- your table here
    where FixedDate between @start_date and @end_date
    for xml path(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

declare @q nvarchar(max)
set @q = '
select Dept, FixedBy, ' + @collist + ' 
from (
    select Dept, FixedBy, FixedDate, TicketCode
        from (
        select *
        from #t -- your table here
    where FixedDate between ''' + convert(varchar(8),@start_date,112) + ''' and ''' + convert(varchar(8),@end_date,112) + '''
    ) as x
) as source
pivot (
    count(TicketCode)
    for FixedDate in (' + @collist + ')
) as pvt
'
exec (@q)
```

Result (using the insert script by @Richard, thx):

```
Dept                 FixedBy    20140305    20140306
-------------------- ---------- ----------- -----------
merlin                Mark      1           1
merlin                Ravi      0           1
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing the pivot concept. but, the result i get has only 1 row. (all the times) could you please modify it, anyway  @Ritchardvivian Query works 100% as said, BUT, i would like to see how this Pivot Concept of yours works. Waiting for an update, BTY, Thank you for the interesting code.

Comment: I looked at the pivot option, but was not sure that this was supported by MySQL. Also did not seem to support the column list dynamically.  I see that you have overcome this limitation by also using Dynamic SQL to create the query that executed using pivot.  Good to see the alternative in action.  Will keep this in mind for future as it seem more flexible.